# Why is the NTP local fudge server no longer reachable?

Tags: centos6, ntp, ntpd

For many years I have had:

```
server 127.127.1.0 # local clock
fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

In my `/etc/ntp.conf` configs - it always worked as I expected it to: ie. was mostly useless but for those odd times where no other server is reachable it was there as a fallback.  I am just setting up a new server CentOS 6.7 and noticed that this LOCL fudge server is never being reached. The output of `ntpq -p`for it is:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l  20h   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I checked my other servers (all CentOS 6.5) and I have apparently not noticed they are behaving this way too. I'm pretty sure this didn't used to be the case and a few searches suggest others local fudge servers don't behave this way.

ntp package is 4.2.6p5 in all cases.

Perhaps this feature has been deprecated, if that is so what has it been replaced with?
*Edit:* After recovering the fresh install `ntp.conf` I see no suggestion of using this feature now, which there was, so this perhaps this is a good hint this is the case.

Or is it just no longer seen as useful? I have seen a few people suggest this even when it works, my view was always it wasn't going to do any harm when the stratum level was set high enough and rest of config was sane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been [deprecated](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/UndisciplinedLocalClock) and is not recommended for general use.

[Orphan mode](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/OrphanMode) is the suggested replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty definitive - not sure why my searches didn't find that yet, just lots of results with people having it override their regular NTP servers.